# How to plot time series with multiple datapoints on each date in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I need to plot a time series of temperature vs dates in R. However, each date have 24 datapoints as the temperature is measured each hour. I guess i need to make each datapoint unique in some way, but I can`t get this to work.

My data looks like this:

```
    dato     time      ampm  temp
 07.09.2012 12:20:17    AM  16.237
 07.09.2012 01:20:17    AM  16.237
 07.09.2012 02:20:17    AM  16.237
 .....
 07.25.2012 12:20:17    AM  16.332
 07.25.2012 01:20:17    AM  16.332
 07.25.2012 02:20:17    AM  16.332
 07.25.2012 03:20:17    AM  16.332
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Combine `dato` and `time` into a POSIXct variable.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want to plot all your data points, i.e. several data points within each date (then @Roland's suggestion is a good start), or if you want to aggregate your data somehow, e.g. mean/median/first/last temp per date.

Answer (score 1):

Below we use the zoo package.  Note that we have used `text=Lines` to keep the example self-contained but in reality we would replace that with something like `file="myfile.dat"` .

```
Lines <- "dato     time      ampm  temp
 07.09.2012 12:20:17    AM  16.237
 07.09.2012 01:20:17    AM  16.237
 07.09.2012 02:20:17    AM  16.237
 07.25.2012 12:20:17    AM  16.332
 07.25.2012 01:20:17    AM  16.332
 07.25.2012 02:20:17    AM  16.332
 07.25.2012 03:20:17    AM  16.332
"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, 
       index = 1:3, tz = "", format = "%m.%d.%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
plot(z)
```

[image]